# How can I import the config file properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, module, config

I'm studying import/export and modules. I was able to import the jQuery file, but am getting an error when trying to import the config file.

[This](https://ibb.co/N6bBHC0) is the error i'm getting:

```
config:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

(I want to use a config file, because it will help me manage api tokens for dev and production.)

I'm trying to import the config file to the jquery file:

Here is the content in the config file:

```
export default {
    WEATHER_API_ENDPOINT: `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?`,
    API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
  }
```

Here is part of the jquery file:

```
import config from './config'

let weatherBaseUrl = config.WEATHER_API_ENDPOINT;
let weatherApiKey = config.API_KEY;

...

export default function handleJquery() {
    $(handleExploreApp);
}
```

Here is the content in the main file:

```
import handleJquery from './jquery.js'

handleJquery()
```

the main file is linked to in the html file like so:

```
  <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

[Here is a link](https://github.com/elireiner/learn-modules) to the repo

(Would webpack help for this?)

Comment: try `WEATHER_API_ENDPOINT: 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?',`

with single quotes

Comment: ` is Template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const Config = {
    WEATHER_API_ENDPOINT: `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?`,
    API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
  } 
export default Config
```